# Lap time formatting code is confusing

Tags: java, time-format

I have this code from school and I can't seem to understand exactly what is it doing. I know it shows a lap time, like those from sports, converted in a minutes, seconds and milliseconds, but I don't understand what the 2 string variable are and what they do.

Here's the code:

```
public String getTimeFormat(long ms){
    String s1 = ""+ms;
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = new SimpleDateFormat("SSS").parse(s1);
    } catch (ParseException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String s2 = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss:SS").format(date);
    return s2;
}
```

Comment: Ask your teacher else read java basics

Comment: Now it's best time for you to take some basic java tutorials

Comment: This is not a place where people solve your homeworks.

Comment: There's no indication that "understanding this code" is homework. The OP is trying to understand existing code. I think it's a reasonable question, myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, this is really bad code in my view.

It's converting the original `ms` value into a string (so 35968 would become "35968") and then parsing that into a `Date`, as if from a format which *only* specifies a number of milliseconds... which is then interpreted as "the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch in the formatter's time zone".

It's then converting that `Date` value into a minutes/seconds/milliseconds format by formatting it with another `SimpleDateFormat`. The milliseconds are only formatted to 2 decimal places, although it's odd to use `:` as a separator here rather than `.`. (It makes it look like an hours/minutes/seconds value, rather than minutes/seconds/milliseconds.)

Both formats use the same time zone, which at least *sort of* avoids problems there. However:

- If the system default time zone had transitions around the Unix epoch, there could still be some oddities
- Fundamentally it's trying to format a *duration* by treating it as a date and time. That's a bad idea
- The exception "handling" is laughable - if an exception is thrown when parsing, the first exception will then be printed and a `NullPointerException` will be thrown by the following line, as `date` will still be null
- If the duration is more than an hour, the information will silently be lost; it's not clear what the desired behaviour is here
- Even if you *did* want to format it this way, it would be simpler to use `new Date(ms)` and then format it with a `SimpleDateFormat` with the time zone set to UTC. There's no need for any string parsing here

I can't easily provide better code without knowing a few more requirements, but if you were trying to replace this code you should consider:

- Given that you have milliseconds, do you definitely only want tens-of-milliseconds precision in the display?
- What do you want to do if `ms` is negative?
- What do you want to do if `ms` represents more than an hour?
- Do you definitely want `:` as the separator between seconds and milliseconds?

You might then want to use `String.format` to format the value. Unfortunately neither Joda Time nor `java.time` in Java 8 has a good way of performing custom `Duration` formatting, which is what you really want here.

Comment: Ok, thank you:) it confused me with the date, but now i understand! thanks a lot!

Comment: I understood that i was converting so i used new Date(ms) and SimpleDateFormat as you suggested and it is working. Also changed the separator:) I can't have negative ms because it is defined already as positive and not more than an hour fortunately:) but really thanks a lot for the help!!

Comment: @LauraMoise: Right - in that case I would add tests at the start of the method to ensure that it *isn't* negative, and that it *isn't* more than an hour. Throw an `IllegalArgumentException` in those cases.